# Doxygen docs for 'extern' variables in C

Tags: c, doxygen, extern

I have `extern` variable in C code:

```
/**
 * Key.
 */
extern key_t key;
```

However, according to Doxygen, this style of documentation is wrong:

```
extern.h:29: error: parameters of member key are not (all) documented (warning treated as error, aborting now)
```

What is the proper way of documenting `extern` variables?

Comment: Did you document the file with `\file`, or set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` in the configuration file?

Comment: No, I haven't documented file with `\file`, is it needed? And moreover I didn't set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES`, why you ask?

Comment: If the file is not documented, and `EXTRACT_ALL` is not set to `YES`, declarations in the file may not get documented.  https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/faq.html#fac_al